# Why java.net.URI does not encode all reserved characters? (java 11)

Tags: java, uri, urlencode, rfc3986

I want to create an instance of java.net.URI using individual URI components, namely:

- scheme
- userInfo
- host
- port
- path
- query
- fragment

There is a constructor in java.net.URI class that allows me to do it, here is a code from the library:

```java
 public URI(String scheme,
               String authority,
               String path, String query, String fragment)
        throws URISyntaxException
    {
        String s = toString(scheme, null,
                            authority, null, null, -1,
                            path, query, fragment);
        checkPath(s, scheme, path);
        new Parser(s).parse(false);
    }
```

This constructor will also encode path, query, and fragment parts of the URI, so for example if I pass already encoded strings as arguments, they will be double encoded.

JavaDoc on this function states:

4. If a path is given then it is appended. Any character not in the unreserved, punct, escaped, or other categories, and not equal to the slash character ('/') or the commercial-at character ('@'), is quoted.
5. If a query is given then a question-mark character ('?') is appended, followed by the query. Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted.
6. Finally, if a fragment is given then a hash character ('#') is appended, followed by the fragment. Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted.

it states that unreserved punct and escaped characters are ***NOT*** quoted, punct characters include:

- `!`
- `#`
- `$`
- `&`
- `'`
- `(`
- `)`
- `*`
- `+`
- `,`
- `;`
- `=`
- `:`

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) reserved characters are:

```
  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

So, if characters `@`, `/` and `+` are reserved, and should always be encoded (or I'm I missing something?), according to the most up to date RFC on URIs, then why does java.net.URI JavaDoc states that it will not encode punct characters (which includes `+` and `=`), `@` and `/`?

Here is a little example I ran:

```java
String scheme = "http";
String userInfo = "username:password";
String host = "example.com";
int port = 80;
String path = "/path/t+/resource";
String query = "q=search+term";
String fragment = "section1";

URI uri = new URI(scheme, userInfo, host, port, path, query, fragment);

uri.toString // will not encode `+` in path.
```

I don't understand, if this is correct behavior and those characters indeed don't need to be encoded, then why are they referred to as "reserved" in an RFC? I'm trying to implement a function that will take a whole URI string and encode it (hence extract path, query, and fragment, encode reserved characters in them, and put the URI back together).

Answer (score 4):

It is exactly because that these characters are reserved, that Java's API *does not* encode them. Being reserved means that they have special meaning when they are not escaped:

from the same section of the RFC you linked:

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting
> characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI.
> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.  Percent-
> encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded octet
> that corresponds to a reserved character, will change how the URI is
> interpreted by most applications.  Thus, characters in the reserved
> set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be
> used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for
> delimiting data subcomponents within a URI.

If `java.net.URI` *always* escaped them, then you would not be able to express whatever special meaning the reserved characters have. You would be only able to create

```
http://username:password@example.com:80/path/t%2B/resource?q=search+term#section1
```

but not

```
http://username:password@example.com:80/path/t+/resource?q=search+term#section1
```

which can be URIs that mean different things, according to the RFC.

Further down that section, it is also said that

> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.

In other words, if "these characters are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that component", then "URI producing applications should *NOT* percent-encode data octets...". This is very much the case in the [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) component, which uses a subset of the reserved characters - `/`, `@`, `:`, and everything in "sub-delims".

This matches what the JavaDoc says about what it doesn't escape. Note that the wording in the JavaDoc (words like "escaped" and "punct") is actually from an older RFC, [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396). With a bit of careful checking, you can see that they are indeed equivalent in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

> So, if characters @, / and + are reserved, and should always be encoded (or I'm I missing something?) ...

The URI spec states:

> *"URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set **unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.**  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII."*

Firstly, it clearly does not say reserved characters "... should always be encoded"

For example, if we examine the syntax rules for `path` we see:

```
  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

and `'+'` is in `sub-delims`.

So `+` should NOT be (automatically) encoded in a `path`.

Comment: Just edited that quote into my own answer, and then saw yours, haha.

Comment: Sorry ... yea ... I just cut straight to the chase :-)